# MySQL join 1 record in table A to many in table B as a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, pivot

I want to query across two tables: **members** and **payments**.

*One* member record could join with *many* payments. However, I need each payment record to be added as an **additional column** as opposed to an additional row.

Here is a simplified example:

### members

```
member_id | first_name | last_name
5         | John       | Smith
```

### payments

```
payment_id | member_id | pay_type   | amount
1          | 5         | VISA       | $20
2          | 5         | Mastercard | $40
3          | 5         | AMEX       | $10
```

### Desired query result

```
member_id | first_name | last_name | payment_id1 | pay_type1 | amount_1 | payment_id2 | pay_type2  | amount_2 | payment_id3 | pay_type3 | amount_3
5         | John       | Smith     | 1           | VISA      | $20      | 2           | Mastercard | $40      | 3           | AMEX      | $10
```

A single row as a result, creating columns for each row in the payments table. Thanks!

Comment: Search for **mysql + pivot**: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+pivot

Comment: Or, to answer your question here. Do it in code, not sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most likely achieve what you want using a pivot table:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: Thanks! There's plenty of resources now that I know what I'm actually searching for.